# Anaconda problems modifying PYHTONPATH in .profile and .bash_profile

Tags: python, bash, terminal, anaconda

So I have my .profile and .bash_profile setup as follows:

[image]

But I am also using the anaconda Python package.

I'm following these set of instructions found here:

http://www.skirt.ugent.be/pts/_install_mac_set_up.html

And receiving this error message:

[image]

"No module named pts"

Does anyone know where I have gone wrong?? There seems to be a comflict with Anaconda and the `pythonpath=` command in the .bash_profile file...?

Any suggestions on how to fix this/marry the two up would be much appreciated!

Comment: what do you get if you run "echo $PYTHONPATH" from the shell?

Comment: @Isogen74 /Users/UCL_Astronomy/Documents/PTS/pts:/Users/UCL_Astronomy/Documents/PTS/pts:

Comment: @Isogen74 Any thoughts?

Comment: Links to documentation and pastes of terminal output are **much** more useful than random screen captures. Links can be viewed for information you may have missed. Text can be copied and pasted to try (and look for formatting/character oddities).

Comment: @EtanReisner Apologies, will update with text and links now.

Comment: For example: According to [this page](http://www.skirt.ugent.be/pts/_install_mac_set_up.html) which I assume is the one you were using you have included one path too many in your `PYTHONPATH` value. You should have stopped at `/PTS` and not ended with `/PTS/pts`.

Comment: @EtanReisner Many thanks, it always takes a fresh eye to see the obvious istake! Now all working fine, thank you very much!

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `PYTHONPATH` incorrectly. You included one path component too many.

From [Configuring paths and aliases](http://www.skirt.ugent.be/pts/_install_mac_set_up.html)

> Add the following lines:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/PTS
alias pts="python -m pts.do"
alias ipts="python -im pts.do"
```

But you added the equivalent of

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/PTS/pts
```

which path *includes* the `pts` module that the error is complaining about.

Remove the `/pts` bit from your `PYTHONPATH` line and things should work.